# UDP receive timeout option linux c

Tags: c, linux, udp

I am setting UDP receive timeout option using something like this:

```
    struct timeval t;
    t.tv_sec = 0;
    t.tv_usec = 5;

    if(setsockopt(destination_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &t, sizeof(t)) == -1){
        perror("Setting SO_RCVTIMEO option in UDP socket for destination RX: ");
        print_error_and_exit("Couldn't set SO_RCVTIMEO option in UDP socket for destination RX");
    }
```

I want to set UDP receive timeout to 5 microseconds, but this is not working.

When there are no packets receive, UDP is taking around at least 4 milliseconds to timeout even if I have set 5 microseconds.

How can I make to timeout in 5 microseconds if no packets available.

I guess may be process going to blocked state, and scheduler schedules other process, and so always it takes around 4 milliseconds. If so, how can I make call to recvfrom() to receive UDP packet to fail without blocking if there is no data to receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 microsecond is a super small duration, you need more time just to switch to the kernel to process your recv system call. 4 ms though sounds a bit long to me.

The fastest you can do is set no timeout at all, use select to check if the socket have a pending packet.

Comment: You can do better than use `select`. `ppoll` has a timeout specifiable in nanoseconds (obviously the kernel won't work to that resolution, but it's better than `select`).

Comment: many thanks, I had never thought about select. I wasted 2 days on finding which part of my program is taking time, it turned out to be recvfrom() blocking for around 4 millisecond, when it should have blocked for 5 microsecond.

Comment: @abligh: If you really need 5 micros, then just set no timeout at all, and then wether the resolution is ns or s, as you pass 0, it's the same.

Comment: sure got it.. I need very small timeout option, because I need to receive from 2 UDP sockets at a time, if I do use non-blocking option for both socket, will it going to use my all CPU time?

Comment: Only if you pass a very short timeout to `select` / `ppoll`

Comment: Can't you use select in blocking mode on both of them, select will return as soon as one of them received something.

You can also consider using to threads, each one doing a blocking recv call.

Comment: @Meraman The kernel works with time slices and normally runs with timer interrupts at 1000HZ, That means that concepts such as timeouts have a resolution of 1 milisecond, and you cannot achieve a timeout as low as 5 microseconds, without possibly doing non-blocking reads - which means you need to loop on recvfrom()/clock_gettime(), hogging the CPU.

Comment: thanks got it. Threads are not option. I am programming for Raspberry Pi, and I think threads are not good option for single core processor.

Comment: Threads are a good option even for a single core processor, your threads will not run simultaneously but still it makes such things super easy. We usually have much more threads than cores, and it's completely fine.

Comment: Yes, but I need to do receive/send and processing in realtime. I had tested threads with Java on raspberry PI, and it was horrible. So decided on single threaded C program, where raspberry will be running only this C program.

Comment: Real time and java do not work well together, mostly because the garbage collector freezes the full VM for a long time every now and then. There are some real time java extensions (e.g. Jamaica) but it's much easier to use C...

Comment: yes thanks, one more thing, can I make C program to run as realtime in linux? Or how can I know schedular timeslice and decrease it?

Comment: linux is not stricly real time but quite close, so just creating threads and giving them high priority should be enough to have something decent. The scheduler timeslice is usually 10 ms, decreasing it is not usually interesting, it will not make your system more reactive: if you have a high priority thread waiting for a UDP recv, it will get the focus as soon as the packet arrives, whatever the scheduler timeslice is. Though you'll still have the latency of a context switch, which is higher than 5 micro seconds.